# applescript assign mouse click to random keystroke

Tags: macos, random, click, applescript, mouse

I am trying to make a script that enables a mouse click to run through a string of keystroke values, moving down the keystrokes one at a time with each successive click. I am not having much luck.

Even better would be if the separate keystrokes can be triggered randomly and not sequentially with a mouse click. Any help would be great. Thanks

```
repeat 10 times
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "TextEdit"
        click (click at {10, 10})

        keystroke "6"
        keystroke "6"
        keystroke "0"
        -- ...
        keystroke "6"
        keystroke "4"
        delay 1

    end tell

end tell
```

end repeat

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your method? What's the goal?

Comment: Hi Pat, thanks for asking. I have an external button that is assigned to a mouse click each time I click the button I want it to run through 10 different keystrokes in order e.g. click 'pressQ' next click 'pressW' next click 'pressE' etc.. even better would be for the clicks to be able to randomly jump to different keystrokes so that they re not in order. (It's for an art project a video jukebox!)

Comment: So you want to write a character to a text file per click?

Comment: Yes that is about right, if I can have a character written in a text file per click I can then use it in my video  software - This has keyboard mapping and when it registers the press of a key I can make the software play a specific video file.

Comment: To track mouse events you'll need an application. You need to be the windows owner. Then you can track clicks inside your window and do whatever you like.